# CSS only horizontal scroll, flex vertical

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a reactive website that changes with the screen width. On a wide screen, scoreDiv has both horizontal and vertical scroll. However, on a smaller width screen, I want scoreDiv to only have horizontal scroll and flex in the vertical direction (I'm not sure if I'm using correct terminology, I hope that makes sense). When I try to use overflow-x: scroll, it also scrolls in the y direction for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

CSS & HTML

```css
#secondRow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#controlSidebar {
    text-align: center;

    border-right: 3px solid teal;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 375px;
}

#scoreDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #secondRow {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #controlSidebar {
    text-align: center;

    width: auto;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid teal;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }

  #scoreDiv {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="secondRow">
  <div id="controlSidebar">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div id="scoreDiv">
    <!--content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that I have a sidebar that stays on the left on a wide screen and stays on the top for a narrow screen. I've updated the code to reflect that. I have also drawn a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svcb0.png) to show what I'm trying to accomplish. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7rgb.png) is the problem I have right now.

Comment: can you create a working fiddle?

Comment: from your code, there is no way to understand your trouble, those flex rules for a single box are just alike a display:block and width:100% everywhere ... only box-sizing and default margins could be in the way ....

Comment: do the pictures help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the overflow and add no wrap to scoreDiv. Aldo add the overflow to secondRow

```
#secondRow {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 380px);
}
#controlSidebar {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 3px solid teal;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    width: 375px;
}
#scoreDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-right: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#controlSidebar will need to be moved outside #secondRow because #secondRow is acting as the container for the scrollable content. I added the following HTML for testing

```
<div id="controlSidebar">
    <!--content-->
    menu
</div>
<div id="secondRow">

    <div id="scoreDiv">
        <!--content-->
        content content 1 content 2 content 3 content 4 content 5 content 6 content 7 content 8 content 9 content 10 content 11 content 12 content 13 content 14 content 15 content 16 content 17 content 18 content 19 content 20 content 21
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried replacing your css into mine (for the non-mobile section), and the problem was still there :/

Comment: I see the HTML has changed since I posted my answer. Checkout this fiddle where the code is working https://jsfiddle.net/bvn2owpv/       I will update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `float`. Use `min-width: 0;` for the right column.
Example: https://codepen.io/schden/pen/jpvVpp